# Why do tweets keep getting recognised as bytes, not strings?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to learn some basic twitter mining skills using Tweepy and how to use CSV files but I am encountering a problem. The code below works correctly, but the variable tweettext (which represents a single tweet) isn't recognised as a string (which is what I was expecting considering it is a tweet). Why is it a byte? Is there any way to convert it into a string?

Here is my code:

```
import tweepy 
import csv

#from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
from authorise_App import consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_secret,access_token

def get_tweets(username):
    
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth) 

    with open('aocTweets.csv', "w", encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_add = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        csv_add.writerow(["created_at", "id", "text"])

        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username, tweet_mode="extended").items(200):

            tweettext = tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')
            print(type(tweettext))
            csv_add.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweettext])

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  
    # Here goes the twitter handle for the user 
    # whose tweets are to be extracted. 
    get_tweets('username')
```

I tried changing my code to `'tweettext = str(tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8'))'` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: if you get bytes then you have to use `decode()`, not `encode()`. `encode()` is used to convert string to bytes.

Comment: BTW: `doesn't work` is the most useless information. If you get error message then show it in question (not in comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you get bytes then you have to use `decode()` to convert to string

`encode()` is used to convert string to bytes.

BTW: you should get error message when you try to use `encode()` with bytes.

---

To send `Unicode` string in socket/network (or save in file) you have to convert it to bytes. And some modules keep received bytes and you can decide if you want to use bytes or decode to string and what encoding you need `utf-8`, `latin1`, `cp1250`, etc.